# What is 上がり refering to in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, compounds

I came across the following paragraph in a book.

> 一日の始まりは、まず基礎{きそ}体力の鍛錬{たんれん}。腹筋、屈伸{くっしん}、腕立{うでた}て伏{ふ}せ。お定まりの筋力トレーニングを、呼吸が**上がり**床{ゆか}に**這{は}いつくばる**まで
>   **繰{く}り返す**。

Is 上がり being used as a [noun plus noun compound](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/27487/26406) with 床 in reference to a "risen floor", as seen in these [online images](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=%e4%b8%8a%e3%81%8c%e3%82%8a%e5%ba%8a%e3%81%ab&FORM=HDRSC2)?

Or is 上がり being used as a reference to the author's moving body as him exercising contextually produces a downward (這いつくばる) then upward (繰り返す) motion, as further evidenced in the following excerpt taken from [heretomurimudamura's answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/62378/26406)?

> "上がります means that something is going up in reference to a past position."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here 上がり is connected not to 床 but to 呼吸(が). 呼吸が上がる is a set phrase meaning "to be out of breath". 息が上がる and 息が切れる mean the same. Perhaps it's related to the thirteenth definition [here](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B). The masu-stem is used to connect two verbs (you know how this works because [you asked about it before](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/70321/5010)).

> 筋力トレーニングを、呼吸が上がり床に這いつくばるまで繰り返す。
>   (Someone) repeats the muscle training until she/he's out of breath and grovels on the floor.

Comment: I didn't know 呼吸が上がる was a set phrase. Can you recommend some books or online sites which would allow me to search Japanese set phrases?

Comment: @Toyu_Frey Hmm, jisho.org lists [息が上がる](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%81%AF%E3%81%8C%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B), but 呼吸が上がる is less common. Still, I think you can suspect this is some phrase because 呼吸が床に這いつくばる ("the breath grovels on the (rising-)floor") makes no sense...

Comment: Weird that the site didn't try to give me 息が上がる as a possible search result when I searched 息が上がり earlier. Because of that I mistook 上がり as to mean this [上がり](https://jisho.org/search/息が上がり) jisho.org has.

Comment: @Toyu_Frey You should use the dictionary form :)

Comment: I wrongly thought 上がり WAS the dictionary form. Of course I'm wrong. Again. (In retrospect you'd think I'd have picked up on this pattern and figured out some way to counteract it, but apparently that's not the case)  :)

Comment: Is the relative clause being connected to 這いつくばる through the connective form? Asking as you mentioned the masu-stem is used to connect two verbs, and I'm wondering if you brought that up because you see it occurring in my sentence.

Comment: @Toyu_Frey Which is "the relative clause"? This sentence has no relative clause (my English translation has no relative clause, either). ～まで does not form a relative clause because it modifies a verb, and 上がる and 這いつくばる are placed in parallel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101495/discussion-between-toyu-frey-and-naruto).